# For-Each Loop Java Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

In my program I need a for-each loop which counts the number of evens in the given array and increments the variable `even` for each one. When I use a standard `for` loop, i.e. `(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++;)`, then the code works fine. However, my assignments requires me to use a for-each loop for this particular problem. Am I doing something wrong?

```
int [] numbers = new int[8];
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
    numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 51 + 50);
}

for (int i : numbers) {
    if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
    }
    else
        odd++;
```

This throws up the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 54
```

Comment: You're already picking each item with the for-each loop, so `if (i % 2 == 0) {` is enough. Here, `i` is the item in your array, not the index.

Comment: In the second loop the varieble i means exact value not index

Comment: that's a very basic mistake from you man!

Answer (score 7):

```
if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
```

Inside your foreach loop, you need not to access it with index. Just `i` is enough as foreach keep on gives you the `element` directly (not the index) inside the array/collection you are using.

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
```

---

```
for (int i : numbers) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            even++;
        }
        else{
            odd++;
        }
  }
```

---

You can actually shorten your codes by eliminating the second loop completely by checking the even or odd in first loop itself.

Comment: So in a for-each loop, it actually references the value rather than just the location in the array?

Comment: @MatthewThibodeauSo when you were using `numbers[i]`, if your element had a value of 2500, you were refering to `numbers[2500]`

Comment: don't you think this is the same answer as above by Dheeraj Joshi. I don't see a value in putting same answers twice.

Comment: @AdeshKumar I have not duplicated. You should have checked the timestamps of the answers. I am the first answerer as far as I know.

Comment: oh! so it's otherwise. Sorry my bad! Neverthless the answer above should go away then.

Answer (score 6):

For each loop in your case will be explained like:

`for (int i : numbers) {`

every integer in array numbers will be placed in `i` one by one

**so,what you are doing wrong is:**

`if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {`

```
for (int i : numbers) {
if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
even++;
}
else {
odd++;
}
```

`i` will not be increasing evrytime loop proceed like in the traditional for loop, here `i` carry the **actual value**

so you should change  from `numbers[i]%2==0` to just `i%2==0`

```
 for (int i : numbers) {
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    even++;
}
else {
    odd++;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `i` is the number itself, not the index. so you should:

```
for (int i : numbers) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) { // <-- use i not numbers[i]
        even++;
    }
    else {
        odd++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `numbers[i]` in `if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0)`, just put `i`.

The `i` in your `for (int i : numbers)` actually stores the elements in the array`(numbers)` from `0th` index up-to the `length` of the array.

In `if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0)`, the `numbers[i]` will give you the element at `ith` index. And the value of `i` is some random number from `(int)(Math.random() * 51 + 50)` which will always gonna be a `number` greater than `50`. So what you're trying to do is accessing some element which is out of bounds of the size of the array that you declared i.e. `8` in `int [] numbers = new int[8]`.

Answer (score 0):

In for Each loop no need to provide numbers[i] so use the following code.
for (int i : numbers) , int i is number present in array. so just put the condition on number itself. If u are using number[i] then it will check the value of i th index , and if any number is greater then your array size it will throw ArrayOutOfBox Exception.

```
 int [] numbers = new int[8];
        int even = 0;
        int odd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 51 + 50);
        }

    for (int i : numbers) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                even++;
            }
            else
                odd++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there are lot many answers. You could achieve same by using java-8  streams as well. Use reducer to find out the even's count and then from length reduce the even's count to get odd's count.

See code below:-

```
   int[] numbers = new int[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 51 + 50);
    }

    int even = Arrays.stream(numbers)
            .reduce(0, (a, b) -> {
                a += b % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                return a;
            });
    int odd = numbers.length - even;
```

Comment: Though +1 for using reducer nicely and the logic to get odds without any much calculation.  Though you should try to use Int stream to create the Array as well.

Comment: I think the focus of this question is to get evens and odds count. I will edit my answer after working on that